# How could I show the view at the bottom of activity layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to show the Google Admob adds at the bottom of the layout. However, it either doesn't show, or it show above the List view, not below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:background="@color/listViewBg"
     >

        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:background="#3871A6" 
             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:paddingTop="5dp" 

             >
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
                android:gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:text="@string/list_header"

                android:textSize="25sp"

                 android:textColor="#FFF"
                   >
            </TextView>




             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                 android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textSize="15sp"

                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:background="@drawable/red_button"
                   style="@style/button_text"
                  >
            </Button>

       </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/listviewlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


             >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


         android:background="@color/listViewBg"
         android:dividerHeight="0dp"
          android:divider="@null"
         > 
    </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/containeradmob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" 

        />
       </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use RelativeLayout in your top layout. Then you define first the buttonlayout2 and the containeradmob, setting the latter as align parent bottom, and then add the list as below the buttonlayout2 and above the containeradmob. That will guarantee to have the ads shown always.